# "??" appearing in URL request in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea

I'm trying to generate an url according some data:

```
private static const historyURL:String = "http://" + BuilderResources.SERVER_IP + "/history/history‏";


var folder:int = int (Math.floor(battleId / 1000));
var url:String = historyURL + folder.toString() + '/' + historyFileName + '.log';
var historyRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
trace(historyRequest.url); //(1)

var historyLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
<add some listeners here>
historyLoader.load(historyRequest);
```

At point (1) correct url is traced. for example:

> http://domainname.com/folder9/filename.log

but when I try to load this request (`historyLoader.load(historyRequest);`) there is an error:

> Error #2032: Stream Error. URL:
>   http://domainname.com/folder??9/filename.log

As you can see, "??" appeared. **Why**?

**UPD:**
looks like "??" added after historyURL whatever it is. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure with `historyUrl` declaration missing, but the culprit potentially appears to be multibyte (UTF-8) characters.

trace() would hide these, but URLRequest would convert these to ASCII, which would reveal the question mark characters. Try temporarily hardcoding `historyUrl` to `http://domainname.com/folder` and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: I found that "??" appears only ofter `historyUrl`. So, made it local, licke this: `var historyRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://" + BuilderResources.SERVER_IP + '/history_test/history' + folder.toString() + '/' + historyFileName + '.log');` ant it worked. I guess that is what you spoke of. I made it myself, but thanks for answer anyway.